# Where are gradle tasks defined

Tags: gradlew

I have a gradle project.

When I type "gradlew tasks" i see a bunch of tasks.

Where are these tasks? How do i see where they are defined?

Answer (score 2):

`gradle help --task <taskname>`

Will give you information about a given task.

Comment: This does not show the path to the task.

Comment: You may be able to infer the path to the task based on the Java package listed for it (under the "Type" heading).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `build.gradle` file? I think they might be there.